Minimal inner product for vectors on the unit sphere
Let $v_1,\dots,v_m\in\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ be a set of vectors. I am trying to find a useful lower bound for: $c:=\max_{i\neq j} \langle v_i,v_j \rangle$, which scales with $m$.
Now, I know of the Welch bounds which provide a lower bound for that, but they are very non-tight in the case when $n$ is fixed and $m$ is large. For example, if $n=2$, then I think we can lower bound $c$ by something close to $1-\frac{2\pi}{m}$, which clearly goes to $1$ as $m\rightarrow \infty$. However, the Welch bounds would only give a lower bound of something close to $\frac{1}{2}$. In general, these bounds always provide a lower bound which looks like $\frac{1}{n}$, although intuitively, this lower bound should increase when fixing $n$ and increasing $m$.
My question is, is there a known tighter lower bound that approaches $1$ when $n$ is fixed while $m$ increases?

This seems like a sphere packing problem

Actually Welch bounds are enough to obtain a bound like the one you want: just impose $m = k^n$ and let $k\to\infty$. You will see that the bound will converge to $1$

I might be missing something, but the Welch bounds are of the form (m-n)/n(m-1). Putting m=k^n and taking k to infinity will get a bound approaching 1/n

read it on your own link to Wikipedia. The Welch bounds are an infinite number of bounds, one for each nonnegative $k$
